# One liner swapping using std::tie

Tags: c++, c++11

In python we can swap two variables as

```
>>> a , b = b , a
```

We can do similar kind of swapping in C++11 as

```
void swap(int &a,int &b)
{
    std::tie(a,b) = std::make_tuple(b,a);
}
```

Above works fine, and at O3 generates similar assembly as

```
void swap(int &a,int &b)
{
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

But my question is it conforming to standards or I am missing something?
Or is it a fluke like...

```
a = (a+b) - (b=a);
```

Which has sequence point issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fine.

The calls to `std::tie` and `std::make_tuple` could occur in any order, but they don't modify `a` and `b`, only create `std::tuple`s with references to and copies of `a` and `b`, respectively. It's only when `operator=` is invoked that any modifications are made through the assigning of the references.

Comment: So, std::make_tuple(a,b) creating copies of a & b  will save the day for us.

Comment: And moment you write "std::tie(a,b) = std::forward_as_tuple(b,a);" ... honeymoon over ... swapping stops working.

Answer (score 5):

There is `std::swap` for this. It has a default implementation of swapping the values by using a temporary value, but for some types (e.g. standard containers) it has an optimized implementation.

Here is some more information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you can use the `std::swap()` template like so:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

std::swap(a,b);
```

Note that in C++11 it is declared in the `<utility>` header file.

Answer (score 2):

Your code moves if possible - else copies - both values into the `tuple` temporary, then copies them back out to the moved-/copied-from variables.  It will work safely for types where those operations have their usual semantics, but may be inefficient for more complex user-defined types.  It obviously requires the types support the move or copy-construction and assignments used.  (Specifically, the assignment only happens after the `tuple` members are set, and if the type has value semantics then at the time of assignment the moved- or copied-from objects being assigned are independent from the values in the `tuple`).

Where available for the type involved, using the Standard Library's `std::swap` is the best option.  Many other types may provide a swap overload that's optimal for them.  If you want a conceptually simple way to create custom `swap` functions for your own types, you *could* use the code you've shown subject to the cons mentioned above.