# swapping values of fundamental type

Tags: c++, swap

I guess we all know how to swap values, but there is another way:

```
constexpr auto assign(auto& ...a) noexcept
{
  return [&](auto const ...v) noexcept { ((a = v), ...); };
}
```

To swap, we need to invoke `assign(a, b)(b, a)`.

Is this an efficient way to swap values for fundamental types? Does it offer more room for optimizations than the usual way?

Comment: I've never seen this "idiom" before, and I do not like it :( A Google search for "assign idiom" only finds this question, so it looks like you made it up.  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22assign+idiom%22+C%2B%2B

Comment: This is hard to read, and appears to copy all the values twice (the standard swap copies one value twice, and the other value ("the rest") once). Where's the benefit supposed to be?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm They might be trying to recreate something like Python's `(a, b) = (b, a)` idiom.

Comment: @JohnBayko: Possibly. That can also [be done with `std::tie`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32759865/10077).

Comment: I've never seen this before and, honestly, I think it's quite poor for readability. I think even assigning as `assign(a, b, c)(1, 2, 3)` is horribly convoluted. Why not just write `a = 1; b = 2; c = 3;` like every other sane programmer in existence would? Much easier to read and understand. The fact that it results in duplication with `assign(a, b)(b, a)` is a byproduct of this nastiness that highlights why it's poor for readability; and this doesn't even touch on the copying issues mentioned above.

Comment: My test produces identical assembly. If you have an interesting result in your benchmark, share it with us, as @HolyBlackCat suggests. Otherwise, I think my answer is all we can offer.

Comment: *"trust implicity without ... asm"* [Here's the asm](https://godbolt.org/z/4f3seEo9M), (almost) identical for all three methods.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat which means you have not (dis)proven anything.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a good way to swap values, even for fundamental types. There is no standard "assign idiom"; this is purely something that you made up.

Even if it works, there's no reason to expect that it would produce faster code than `std::swap`, which *is* a standard, well-known idiom.

I strongly recommend that you use `std::swap` instead, so folks reading your code will understand, without having to Google.

Comment: reciting canon does not invalidate my "idiom". You provided no asm, no quotes from the Standard, no insight whatsoever.

Comment: @user1095108 Your question was: "Is this a good way to swap", the answer is no. You have now changed it to: "Is this an efficient way to swap "- the answer is: it's at best as good as `std::swap`. Please don't obfuscate your code if you are planning for other people to use it. Lastly, asm has been provided to you already in the comments.

Comment: I did not change/delete anything, it was the mods, I actually reverted some changes they made. Anyway, the asm failed to show any difference between what `std::swap()` and "idiom" compiled into, as far as I can remember. So it was a failed attempt to shoot down the question.

Comment: @user1095108 I have no idea how you reached that conclusion. Nobody is trying to "shoot down the question", we are trying, and have succeeded, in answering it as it was stated. The moderator attempted to link together all your comments (which you have since deleted), in an attempt to clarify your question.  Even still, with your changes taken into account, the question has been answered. At this point, I consider your comments nothing but spam.

Answer (score 4):

Since you keep asking for theoreticals in the comments: Compiler optimizations are based around whether the compiler can see common patterns to transform them into better code based on whatever the optimization metric is.

To that end, the compiler can be *really smart* at figuring out that the following is a swap:

```cpp
// Conventional (simplified) swap definition
auto swap(int& a, int& b) -> void {
    const int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

In the code you provide, it should be *almost equivalent* **for fundamental types only**, since it will see the parameters `const auto...v` as the `tmp` object -- however it will see two sets of parameters for the copies. If we flatten a transformation of `assign(a,b)(b,a)`, what the compile really sees from the template expansion is:

```cpp
const auto v1 = a;
const auto v2 = b;
b = v1;
a = v2;
```

It's a similar expression to the standard `swap`, but not quite the same as to what compilers have been trained to recognize for several decades of optimizations. *Most likely*, the compilers will see this as an equivalent transformation, and produce the same assembly -- which is the case with both [`gcc` and `clang`](https://godbolt.org/z/4f3seEo9M) <sup>(Credit to @HolyBlackCat for the Godbolt link)</sup>.

Please note that compilers are **really smart** at optimizing code written in conventional/expected ways. What they tend to dislike and struggle with is attempts to be clever. In particular, `assign(a,b)(b,a)` requires the compiler to flatten the inputs to make the optimization in the first place -- whereas the conventional `swap(a,b)` is spelt out for it. Basically: at *best* you will get the same as just doing things the conventional way.

**To that end, this is not a *good* way to swap values**. This likely does *not* provide better optimizations (if anything, likely slightly worse).

If we expand this definition to include generics, it gets worse since the `const auto` provides more copies, and does not perform proper moves (and proper move-semantics also help the compiler as well). Additionally it doesn't semantically read as a "`swap`", whereas `swap(a,b)` or even `std::tie(a,b) = std::make_tuple(b,a)` is much less ambiguous.

---

Also this is not an "idiom" as this has *never* been established by usage as having been a pattern.

Comment: Doing unconventional things is a tough road. The "system", computers and humans alike,  is optimized for being conventional. You'll find it easier to approach stuff like this question if you can come in with a lot of homework, benchmarks etc...,  already done because if you can't prove you're onto something fairly quickly, you'll get tuned out.

Comment: @user4581301 the tough road is sometimes the only road.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes some sense if you were assigning multiple values at once, where some of the assignee (not sure that's the term?) might be changed in the process.

For instance, doing a rotate:

```cpp
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30;
a = b;
b = c;
c = a; // oops you might wanted c = 10, but c is actually 20 now.
```

---

However, if you are only swapping 2 values, then `std::swap` is probably the better way to go, in both readability and optimizability.

While readability is subjective, at least to me, `swap(a, b)` is easier to understand, whereas `assign(a, b)(b, a)` doesn't imply the idea of swapping directly.

Optimizability needs to be benchmarked to be certain, but as far as I know, `std::swap` is well optimized for basic types, and I do not think your way would further optimize it. However, I can not give you a sure answer without actually benchmarking it.

Comment: I don't really care about std::swap or readability or style and my question does not refer to any of these.

Comment: @user1095108 You asked if this is a good way of swap values for fundamental types, where you did not define what *good* should mean. To me, I think an easy to understand api is part of being good.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: Once you know what he's saying, then we realize that he intended to define "good" as "more room for optimizations than the usual way". (And the answer is no, it's worse)